# Не могу вызвать массив из класса в метод

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

С++ ругается, пишет, что

> аргумент "int" несовместим с параметром типа "int *"
> Программа разделена на 3 файла:
> **Set.h**

```
class Set {
private:
    int* a;
    int k;
public:
    Set();
    Set(int a);
    int GetArr() {
        return *a;
    }
    int GetK() {
        return k;
    }
};
void intersec(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z);
void combine(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z);
void differ(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z);
```

**Set.cpp**

```
#include "Set.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Set::Set() {
    k = 0;
    a = new int;
}
Set::Set(int x) {
    k = x;
    *a = new int[k];
    cout << "Enter array values: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cin >> a[];
    }
}
void intersec(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z) {
    int size = 0;
    bool flag;
    cout << "Intersection array: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < x1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y1; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[i]) {
                flag = true;
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
                if (z[l] = x[i]) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                z[size] = x[i];
                size++;
                cout << z[size] << " ";
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void combine(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z) {
    
    cout << "Combined array: \n";
    int size = x1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        z[i] = x[i];
    }
    size += y1;
    for (int i = size-y1; i < size; i++) {
        z[i] = y[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << z[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void differ(int x1, int y1, int* x, int* y, int* z) {
    cout << "Arrays' difference: \n";
    if (x1 > y1 || x1 == y1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y1; i++) {
            z[i] = x[i] - y[i];
            cout << z[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < x1; i++) {
            z[i] = x[i] - y[i];
            cout << z[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Set.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k1, k2;
    cout << "Enter sizes of arrays: \n";
    cin >> k1 >> k2;
    Set s1(k1);
    Set s2(k2);
    Set s3;
    intersec(s1.GetK(), s2.GetK(), s1.GetArr(), s2.GetArr(), s3.GetArr());
    combine(s1.GetK(), s2.GetK(), s1.GetArr(), s2.GetArr(), s3.GetArr());
    differ(s1.GetK(), s2.GetK(), s1.GetArr(), s2.GetArr(), s3.GetArr());
}
```

Не могу понять, как именно мне нужно описать функцию *GetArr()*, чтобы она нормально возвращала массив?

Comment: Ну так `int* GetArr(){ return a; }`? Только это несколько, гм... нарушает принцип инкапсуляции...

Comment: @Harry 
я поэтому и написал свой вопрос, как мне нужно описать функцию _GetArr()_, чтобы она возвращала массив заданный ранее? Или мне нужно в конструкторе _Set(int x)_ как-то её задавать?

Comment: А я что вам ответил?... Другое дело, что вы и конструктор неверно написали... Да и все ваши функции для работы с множествами должны и принимать множества — тогда и нарушения инкапсуляции не будет. Вы спросили, какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей — я ответил, правой. Вы же не спрашивали, как забивать гвозди (кстати, и после ответа тоже не спросили).

Comment: Вдогонку — да и разность множеств — это совсем не разность их элементов!

Comment: @Harry подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно исправить код? В условии задачи сказано, что в классе Set есть два поля - указатель на массив и размер массива. Конструктор класса по заданному значению k выделяет память под k элементов и заполняет их, считывая значения элементов с клавиатуры. Нужнл реализовать методы, вычисляющие пересечение, объединение и разность двух заданных
объектов класса Set.

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам [вариант с реализацией пересечения](https://ideone.com/6lGcla). Остальные два (а равно чтобы в множестве не могли оказаться два одинаковых элемента) допишите сами...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Set
{
    unsigned int count, size;
    int * data;
public:
    Set(unsigned int count = 0, int def = 0)
        :count(count),size(count ? count : 2)
    {
        data = new int[size];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            data[i] = def;
    }
    Set(const Set& s)
        :count(s.count),size(s.count ? s.count : 2)
    {
        data = new int[size];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            data[i] = s.data[i];
    }
    Set& operator = (const Set& s)
    {
        if (this != &s)
        {
            delete[] data;
            count = s.count;
            size  = s.size;
            data  = new int[size];
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                data[i] = s.data[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Set()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    Set& operator << (int n)
    {
        if (count == size)
        {
            int * tmp = new int[size*2];
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                tmp[i] = data[i];
            delete[] data;
            data = tmp;
        }
        data[count++] = n;
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Set& s)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
            os << s.data[i] << " ";
        return os << endl;
    }

    friend Set intersection(const Set& a, const Set& b);

};

Set intersection(const Set& a, const Set& b)
{
    Set r;
    sort(a.data,a.data+a.count);
    sort(b.data,b.data+b.count);
    for(unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
        i < a.count && j < b.count;)
    {
        if (a.data[i] < b.data[j]) i++;
        else if (b.data[j] == a.data[i])
        {
            r << a.data[i++];
            j++;
        }
        else j++;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Set s1;
    s1 << 1 << 2 << 4 << 6;
    Set s2;
    s2 << 2 << 4 << 8 << 12;
    cout << s1 << s2;

    cout << intersection(s1,s2);
}
```

Comment: Ну и кому что не понравилось? :) От кого минус?

Comment: #include <algorithm> - судя по всему использование вот этого)
Во всяком случае мне решение с использованием этой библиотеки не подходит)
Максимум iostream

Comment: Ну напишите свою сортировку. Да, и еще покажите мне в вопросе текст "*без привлечения алгоритмов стандартной библиотеки*". Где он там? в каком месте? Приучайтесь задавать вопросы ясно и точно. Знаете, как злит, когда по 5 раз переписываешь ответ, потому что спрашивающий каждый раз вспоминает о еще каком-то условии, которого и близко не было, но которое вдруг надо выполнить? Наверное, не знаете, иначе бы так некорректно не поступали. Так что минус не мне, минус вам...

Comment: P.S. Впрочем на ваш *конкретный вопрос* полный и точный ответ был дан в первом комментарии... "Ну так `int* GetArr(){ return a; }`"

Comment: прошу прощения, что вызвал в вас столько негативных эмоций. Я здесь впервые ещё не привык к правилам сообщества.